# Why are NA's being created when subsetting data.frame's with conformable dimensions and no NA's?

Tags: r

There are no NA values in the items I'm using to subset these data.frame's by basic R indexing, yet almost half become NA's in my result. The dimensions are conformable and I checked each piece of the matching to make sure that it works in isolation.

Sampling the data so that I can use `dput()` isn't viable on this one because it breaks the matching, thus I uploaded the .RDS data to GitHub:

https://github.com/hack-r/stackoverflow_NA_question

To download files from GitHub you can either clone the repo or click the file then click the "Download" button. To clone the repo type `git clone https://github.com/hack-r/stackoverflow_NA_question.git`.

```
model_data            <- readRDS("model_data.RDS")
StartDates.next3.prev <- readRDS("startDates.next3.prev.RDS")
pred                  <- readRDS("pred.RDS")

table(is.na(pred))
# FALSE 
# 156930

table(is.na(model_data$flag_prev))
# FALSE 
# 52716

nrow(pred) == length(model_data$flag_prev[model_data$flag_prev=="Y"])
# [1] TRUE

StartDates.next3.prev$Start_Date[1]
# [1] "2016-01-04"

table(model_data$matched_start_date[model_data$flag_prev=="Y"]==startDates.next3.prev$Start_Date[1])
# FALSE  TRUE 
# 21872  9514 


tmp <- pred$Enroll.in.term.1[model_data$flag_prev == "Y" &
                             model_data$matched_start_date ==
                             StartDates.next3.prev$Start_Date[1]]

table(is.na(tmp)) # Why are 4,130 NA??
# FALSE  TRUE 
# 5384  4130
```

There should be 9,514 resulting observations, which there are, however they should all be non-NA.

Comment: You tested `table(is.na(pred))`  so the preds are not NA,  but you did not test the thing that you are using `pred$Enroll.in.term.1`.   What do you get from `table(is.na(pred$Enroll.in.term.1))` ?

Comment: @G5W  `FALSE 
31386 `

Comment: **Update**: I found a work around, but would still like to understand the problem. The workaround is to first subset `model_data` like this: `model_data <- model_data[model_data$flag_prev == "Y",]` then to subset it as in the question using only the 2nd condition. Makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
length(pred$Enroll.in.term.1)
# 31386

x <- model_data$flag_prev == "Y"
y <- model_data$matched_start_date ==  StartDates.next3.prev$Start_Date[1]

sum(which((x & y) == T) > 31386)
# 4130
```

The problem is that the `model_data` has more rows than `pred`. So the logic vector you used to subset is much longer than `pred`. So there will be exactly 4130 NAs.